# How to make node edit form meta panel accordions default to closed?

Tags: theming, 9

When editing a node the meta panel fieldset accordions default to being open if they contain data.

I understand why this has been done, but I think it makes for a very noisy and potentially confusing UI for my editors.

How could I go about making these closed by default?

[image: meta panel with accordions open]

[image: meta panel with accordions open]

Comment: Just wanting to confirm that this also happens with Drupal 8

Comment: Doesn't occur on D8, or atleast not with the default D8 admin theme.

Comment: On a fresh latest D9 9.03 using Claro experimental admin theme I don't see this issue either. They are all closed as expected. Any JS errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Sorry I was not being clear. I meant once populated and upon re-editing they are open. Seven and Claro. 8 & 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different approaches to change this behaviour. For instance, you could choose between these two at least:

- CSS + JS: using a selector like .layout-region-node-secondary (depending on Theme), you could loop using a jQuery $.each() over the different 'details' and, if you find the 'open' property, remove it.
- PHP: Using [Hook Event Dispatcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher), you could attach to the node alter event and upon firing, you could just alter the form accessing the $form / $form_state variables and removing the CSS from the items you'd like to.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @jbarrio. I don't do much coding I was hoping there might be a module for this.